# Write html from XSLT

Tags: xslt

Take the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="desktop.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<desktop>
  <tag name="h1" caption="hello"/>
</desktop>
```

I have an XSLT that will take the name attribute of the tag element and create the appropriate html element

Snippet from the xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> 

   <xsl:template match="tag">
    <{@name}>{@caption}</{@name}>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which of course is not working, due to the < > characters (I suppose)

How can I come around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `<xsl:element>`.  See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_element.asp).

For example:

```
<xsl:element name="@name"><xsl:value-of select="@caption"></xsl:element>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to XSL and never saw this tag

Answer (score 0):

Use `<xsl:element>` instead which will create a new node. For example, I've once used the following code to create automatically nested headings in HTML:

```
<xsl:variable name="extlevel" select="count(ancestor::External[not(@link)])"/>   
<xsl:element name="h{$extlevel + 2}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:element>
```